# "An all night curfew _______________ yesterday following ...."

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice

"An all night curfew _______________ yesterday following  the violent clashes between...."

My question is that when we complete this sentence with "is reported to have been declared " or "was reported to have been declared" , is there any difference in meaninig and

can we say

"An all night curfew is reported to have been declared  yesterday following  the violent clashes between...."

after let's say 10 years later .I mean using "is " could also imply the incident occured recently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"An all night curfew is reported..." and "An all night curfew was reported..." are actually two different phrases, grammatically. The first attributes "reported" to "curfew" as if it were an adjective. The second states that sometime in the past, someone reported that a curfew was declared (in other words, "reported" isn't an adjective here).

The "is reported" phrase implies that the speaker or his organization only recently got word that the curfew was declared yesterday (or ten years ago, whichever the case may be), and perhaps also that the incident is still being talked about. "Was reported" means that the curfew still happened at the same time, but the speaker or his organization knew about it some time in the past.